SyCL accessors in classes in buffers
i want to implement a BigFloat (arbitrary precision float) application on the GPU and i thought using SyCL would be a good solution for this.
The basic C++ implementation works on a vector of bytes and functions good.
My idea was to create a seperate class and copy of all methods that don't allocate data and use an accessor to a buffer that is created from the vector of the original class.
This buffer is correctly allocated and the accessor is stored as an attribute in the SyCL BigFloat class. The original instance is alive during the complete process.
Every kernel invocation has to work on its own BigFloat instance. My idea was to create a buffer of SyCL BigFloats and an accessor to that array. The problem: how would i initialize it? I need to create the accessors of each SyCL BigFloat to initialize the buffer, for this i would need a invocation in the Queue, but i can't declare a buffer in a Queue without receiving a segmentation fault!
Some code:
struct BigFloat {
  void allocate(); // creates the buffer from data
  BigFloatSycl to_gpu(sycl::handler &h) const; // creates the accessor to the buffer from allocate
  // ...
protected:
  sycl::buffer* data_gpu;
  std::vector<char> data;
};
struct BigFloatSycl {
  // ...
protected:
  sycl::accessor data; // accesses the buffer created from the "parent" BigFloat
}

A application like
    queue Q;
    std::vector<BigFloat> as(100);
    std::vector<BigFloat> bs(100);
    std::vector<BigFloatSyCL> asycls(100);
    std::vector<BigFloatSyCL> bsycls(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      as[i] = BigFloat(0.988);
      bs[i] = BigFloat(0.012);
      as[i].allocate();
      bs[i].allocate();
    }
    buffer abuff(asycls.data(), range<1>{asycls.size()});
    buffer bbuff(bsycls.data(), range<1>{bsycls.size()});
    Q.submit([&](auto &h) {
      sycl::stream out(1024, 256, h);
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        asycls[i] = as[i].to_gpu(h);
        bsycls[i] = bs[i].to_gpu(h);
      }
      accessor aaccess(abuff, h, read_write);
      accessor baccess(bbuff, h, read_write);
      h.parallel_for(100, [=](item<1> i) {
        out << *(aaccess[i]) << "+" << *(baccess[i]) << " = ";
        aaccess[i] += baccess[i];
        out << *(aaccess[i]) << "\n";
      });
    });
    Q.wait();

Actually works, but returns completely random values.
Thank you for your help!

Unfortunately, the way that you're trying to use accessors probably won't work. You're trying to pass a buffer<BigFloatSycl>, but that isn't legal because an accessor is not a device_copyable type.
Instead of using buffers, take a look at SYCL Unified Shared Memory (USM) functionality. USM lets you allocate memory, where pointers to the memory can be used directly on the device, allowing you to skip buffers and accessors. In particular, shared USM memory is convenient because you can modify and access it both on the host and the device. You can also mix buffers and USM if required.
